# Functional Analysis Reference Books

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm taking a measure-theory based graduate course on Functional Analysis that covers essentially Folland's Chapter 5-9.  Is there another book that I could reference that perhaps has wordier exposition that explains things in a bit more detail (not Rudin please).  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Erwin Kreyszig's book Introductory Functional Analysis is very good and I think one of the standard recommended texts. In my opinion the book is very very good with lots of clear exposition and plenty of exercises with some solutions.

It can be found [here](http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/spns/cdm/resources/Kreyszig%20-%20Introductory%20Functional%20Analysis%20with%20Applications.pdf).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, is there any measure theory based functional analysis books, I looked through this book and I don't believe it uses measure theory

Comment: I'm not sure about a textbook that teaches both but I found these notes (https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~cannarsa/cam_0607.pdf) which seem to do both although they seem to lack exposition.

Comment: Alternatively you could learn measure theory from say Tao's book (https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf) which is excellent and then go through Kreyszig at the same time. Personally I learned measure theory first (from Tao) and then did Kreyszig.

Comment: Hi I have already taken a course on measure theory so I don’t need a book to learn it.  I mean is there a book similar to Follands that teaches functional analysis using measure theoretic concepts.  For example Folland’s Chapter 7 is on radon measures and he uses measure theory concepts for chapters 8 and 9